# Fast factoring algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I quickly find all factors of a number?

e.g.:

> digit: 20
>   factors: {1*20, 2*10, 4*5, 5*4, 10*2, 20*1}

Comment: No, i will using it to solves a Problem.

Comment: *"That is fastest and briefly."*  Pay someone a lot of money.

Comment: Better solutions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647059/finding-factors-of-a-given-integer

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a problem for which no good solution is known. For this reason, RSA encryption actually depends on the computational difficulty of factoring numbers. See: [Integer Factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

However, you may be able to speed up the algorithms already given by only looking at numbers up to the square root of `n`, and checking if they are factors by checking if `n % i == 0`. If this is true, you can find the corresponding factor greater than `n^(.5)` by taking `n / i`.

Comment: A number can have factors greater than it's square root. For example 16, while sqrt(16) is equal to 4, one of the factors of 16 is 8.

Comment: @cNduo yes, 2 would be the factor < sqrt(16). Then 16 / 2 = 8

Answer (score 3):

If the number that you want to find the factors for happens to be odd, you only need to test odd numbers because it is impossible to have an even factor for an odd number.  So with a pre-check up front, you can save yourself some processing.

```
private static List<Integer> findFactors(int num)
{
    int incrementer = 1;
    if (num % 2 != 0)
    {
        incrementer = 2; //only test the odd ones
    }
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= num / 2; i=i+incrementer)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    list.add(num);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: If i wanted to return an array, or do it without lists entirely, how would i do it?

Comment: I've incorporated the idea of determining the incrementer based on whether the number is even or odd, in a faster solution I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45789083/4660897), on a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

Go through a loop applying modulus to all of the intermediate numbers.

```
X=1;
WHILE(X<=20)
 IF 20%x == 0
 THEN FACTOR!
 X++;
END
```

Comment: X > 10(except 20) It's make waste time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wish to go for the modulus operator( % ).

E.g

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factor {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Enter a number whose factors are to be calculated: ");
     Scanner scanNum = new Scanner(System.in);
     int numFac = 0;
     if(scanNum.hasNextInt())  {
        numFac = scanNum.nextInt();
       }

     System.out.println("The Factors of the entered number are:-");

     for(int i = 1; i <= numFac; i++)   {
        if(numFac%i == 0)   {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
          }
     }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Integer[] findFactors(int d)
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= d/2; i++)
    {
        if(d % i == 0) list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    list.add(new Integer(d));
    return (Integer[]) list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer[] list = findFactors(20);
    for(Integer i : list) System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
4
5
10
20
```

Comment: If d is even haft of loof is waste time 
e.g 
10000 maximum factor(except it self) is 5000 and 5001 - 4999 is waste time

Comment: Yep, just iterate up to half of the original number to find all divisors except the number itself!

Comment: @Flueras Bogdan You are totally right. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER; i++) {
    if (NUMBER % i == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have waste time in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FactorGenerator{      
  private int number;       
  private int i;           
  public FactorGenerator(int numberToFactor){      
    number = numberToFactor;   
  }

  public int nextFactor(){
     while(number % i == 0){
        System.out.print((Math.round(i)) + " "); 
        number =((number / i));
        return i;     
     }     
     return i;     
 }     

 public boolean hasMoreFactors(){      
   for ( i = 2; i <= number; i++){      
     nextFactor(); 
   }
  return false;      
 }
```

}

```
Test Program:      
import java.util.Scanner;        
 public class FactorgeneratorTester{          
   public static void main (String [] args){           
       Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);         
       System.out.println("input the value");       
       int number = in.nextInt();       
       FactorGenerator fg = new FactorGenerator(number);             
           if (fg.hasMoreFactors()){      
             System.out.println(fg.hasMoreFactors());      
           }            
   }
```

}

the input
210
output
2 3 5 7

Comment: What about 1, 6, 10, 15, 21, 30, 35, 70, 105, 210?