# Please discussing my Java code to find Factors(It's Correct?)

Tags: java, algorithm

Do  you  have  another  solution for solve Factor problem?

Comment: If this is your homework, you should add the homework tag to the question.

Comment: no i using it to solves problem but i'll check it's correct.

Comment: No, it doesn't work: it thinks 35 is a prime number. This is almost a duplicate of your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773462/which-is-the-best-algorithm-for-find-factors-implements-by-java), it would be better if you edited that rather than posting a new question.

Comment: Doing %3==0 does not prove something is odd

Comment: number can be odd and prime in same time.

Comment: Yes, but your method of checking if a number is odd is broken - not all odd numbers are divisible by 3. Case in point, 35.

Comment: Try your program with an input of 35. Does it do what you expect?

Comment: @Landric  //odd number(not prime)

Comment: @1eftHer0: interesting approach to bugfixing ; ). Now, does it do what you expect for an input of 49? This could go on for some time... I'm beginning to suspect we're being trolled...

Comment: @OpenSauce i think this solution have many bug fixing by (n%3 == 0 || n%5 == 0 || n%7 == 0) best way to solve this problem is random all digit. yes easyway.

Comment: bug on this program it from i try to use prime but prime is really hard to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

A few comments.  Firstly, as @OpenSource pointed out, this code does not work correctly.  You should probably simplify your approach by forgetting primes at the top level.  Primes do not need to be treated separately.

Some comments on specific lines of code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

At this point you know that there are two factors, 1 and n.  Why not add them immediately to the list?

```
if(i > n/2) break; //optimize
```

Why do you recalculate `n/2` if n hasn't changed since last time?

```
if(n % i == 0) list.add(new Integer(i));
```

If `i` is a factor then `(n / i)` is also a factor.  Every time you get `n % i == 0` you have found two factors.

```
}else if(n%3 == 0 && n%2 != 0 && n != 3 && n != 1){   //odd number
```

This doesn't work and takes far too much effort to do it.  You have already looked at even numbers, what is left must be odd.

```
}else{ //prime
```

No, what is left isn't prime.  And there is one even prime number as well.

```
for(int a:list){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

You might want to sort `list` first, before printing.

Comment: +1 for making the effort. One thing I spotted: beware of the case `i == n / i` (don't add the same factor to the list twice).