# How do i find a factor of an integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I need to create a calculator where the user inputs a number, and it calculates the factors, cube and square of the given number.

Below is the code i am using.. I have NO idea how to work out the factor. Any advice would be appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', estimateTotal);

function estimateTotal(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var initial2 = document.getElementById('initial').value;
 
 document.getElementById('factor').value = 0;
 document.getElementById('sqaure').value = initial2 * initial2;
 document.getElementById('cube').value = initial2 * initial2 * initial2;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculator" method="POST">
    <p>Please enter a number between 0 and 50 <input name="initial" id="initial" type="text" size="20" required><button id="calculate">Calculate</button></p>
    <p>The Factorial of your number is: <input name="factor" id="factor" class="factor" type="text" size="20"></p>
    <p>The Square of your number is:<input name="sqaure" id="sqaure" class="sqaure" type="text" size="20"></p>
    <p>The Cube of your number is:<input name="cube" id="cube" class="cube" type="text" size="20"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647059/finding-factors-of-a-given-integer

Comment: Use a factoring algorithm. Search for "integer factoring algorithm" on Google. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization. By the way, your HTML refers to "factorial"; are you interested in factorials, or factors (of which an integer may of course have more than one)?

Comment: Factor != Factorial. What do you really need to calculate?

Comment: Defnitly Factor, the html part is wrong. :)

Comment: Write a function with initial2 as input parameter and assign the output of this function to document.getElementById('factor').value. You can find the function at the link shared in the first comment

Answer (score 2):

```
  **recursive JavaScript function factor(n)**

 **Check this link:** **http://www.javascripter.net/math/primes/factorization.htm**

function factor(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1!=0 || n==0) return ''+n;
 if (n<0) return '-'+factor(-n);
     var minFactor = leastFactor(n);
 if (n==minFactor) return ''+n;
 return minFactor+'*'+factor(n/minFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for both factor and factorial

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', estimateTotal);

function estimateTotal(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var initial2 = document.getElementById('initial').value;
 
 document.getElementById('Factorial').value = fact(initial2);
  document.getElementById('factor').value = factors(initial2);
 document.getElementById('sqaure').value = initial2 * initial2;
 document.getElementById('cube').value = initial2 * initial2 * initial2;
 
}


   function fact(n)
            {
                if(n == 0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return (n*fact(n-1));
            }


  function factors(num)
{
 var
  n_factors = [],
  i;
 
 for (i = 1; i <= Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); i += 1)
  if (num % i === 0)
  {
   n_factors.push(i);
   if (num / i !== i)
    n_factors.push(num / i);
  }
 n_factors.sort(function(a, b){return a - b;});  // numeric sort
 return n_factors;
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter a number between 0 and 50 <input name="initial" id="initial" type="text" size="20" required><button id="calculate">Calculate</button></p>
<p>The Factorial of your number is: <input name="factor" id="Factorial" class="factor" type="text" size="20"></p>

<p>The Factor of your number is: <input name="factor" id="factor" class="factor" type="text" size="20"></p>
<p>The Sqaure of your number is:<input name="sqaure" id="sqaure" class="sqaure" type="text" size="20"></p>
<p>The Cube of your number is:<input name="cube" id="cube" class="cube" type="text" size="20"></p>
```